# If every convergent subsequence converges to the same limit, does the whole sequence converge to that limit?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

$(E,d)$ be a metric space and $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq E$ be relatively compact.

Assume that there is a $x\in E$ such that every **convergent** subsequence converges to $x$. Does it already follow that $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is convergent and converges to $x$?

The convergence of $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ to $x$ is equivalent to the assertion that every **aribtrary** subsequence is convergent and converges to $x$; but we only know that every subsequence, for which we a priori assume that it is convergent, converges to $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the original sequence be $\sigma$, and let $K=\operatorname{cl}\{x_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$; by hypothesis $K$ is compact. If $\sigma$ does not converge to $x$, there are an $\epsilon>0$ and a subsequence $\sigma_1=\langle x_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ such that $d(x_{n_k},x)\ge\epsilon$ for all $k\in\Bbb N$. Clearly $\sigma_1$ is a sequence in the compact set $K$, so it has a convergent subsequence $\sigma_2=\langle x_{n_{k_i}}:i\in\Bbb N\rangle$. But $\sigma_2$ is also a subsequence of $\sigma$, so by hypothesis it converges to $x$, contradicting the fact that $d(x_{n_{k_i}},x)\ge \epsilon$ for each $i\in\Bbb N$. Thus, $\sigma$ must converge to $x$.

Comment: I was thinking of counterexamples in $l^2(\Bbb R)$

Answer (score 1):

What about the following example in the interval (0,2): $1,\frac{1}{2},1,\frac{1}{3},1,\frac{1}{4},1,\frac{1}{5},1,\frac{1}{6},1,\frac{1}{7},\dots$

Every convergent subsequence converges to 1, but the entire sequence does not converge

Comment: the sequence set is not compact.

Comment: right, fixed (if I understand the correctly the definition of relatively compact, then (0,2) is relatively compact in [0,2] )

Comment: it needs to be only relatively compact, i.e. its closure needs to be compact.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relatively_compact_subspace

Comment: the subsequence ${\frac{1}{n}}$ converges to $0$

Comment: but 0 is not in the (0,2)

Comment: oh sorry, I thought the hypothesis required the space to be complete.

Comment: but again, the sequence set is not relatively compact

Comment: why not? its closure is $\{1/n : n \geq 1\} \cup \{0\}$

Comment: that's not a subset of $(0,2)$

Comment: arrr, right! sorry

Comment: I misread the question. the sequence needs to be relatively compact, but E is arbitrary